# How to make a selection of data from a specific range of an array in a loop?

Tags: c#

I'm making a simple console text game in C#.

In it, I have an array randomly filled with integers from 0 to 2 (0 - room with enemies, 1 - room with healing, 2 - room with gold). There are 15 rooms in total (5 blocks of 3 rooms each).

```
int[] rooms = new int[15]; 
Random rand = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Length; i++)
{
    rooms[i] = rand.Next(3);
}
```

The player makes a choice "which room he will enter" 1, 2 or 3. You need to correlate his choice with the array data. On the first iteration (when i=0) it's easy.

```
//passing through half of the rooms from the total number of rooms in the array

for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Length / 3; i++) 
{
   Console.WriteLine($"You enter a block of rooms № {i + 1}!\n\n
   Choose which room to enter - 1, 2 или 3?\n");

   int choice = rooms[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()) - 1];
}
```

But I can't figure out how to fix this code so that it works for the next iterations as well (when i = 1, 2, 3...)?

`int choice = rooms[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()) - 1 + ???];`

Comment: Trying to understand. You have 5 "blocks" (which I'm assuming represents 5 steps through the game). Each block has three rooms. In each block, one has an enemy, one has healing and one has gold. The player is to walk from block to block. Are my guesses correct? Also, I recommend you don't use `rooms[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())`. Create a function that does the ReadLine, tests and converts the string to an `int` with `int.TryParse` and then tests that the int is in range, asking the user to re-enter the number if it's not parsable or out of range

Comment: Your loop is not going to evenly create 3 of each - they are random.  Better (much) to create an array (or List) with the exact contents you need and shuffle it.  If you want blocks or sets, then make a set of 3 blocks, shuffle and copy to the main dispersal array (or list)

Comment: Assuming my guesses are correct, consider how you might do this in the real world.  I'd grab 3 monopoly houses and stuff each with one of yellow, red and green Play-Doh.  Then I'd shuffle them (shaking them in my hands) and lay them out for the player - "Pick one".  For the next move, I'd just repeat the process using the same houses, repeating it for a total of 5 moves.  Now look up "shuffle algorithm" and think how you could implement my Play-Doh based game.

Answer (score 0):

Because there are 3 rooms per block, you can do `...+(i*3)` like below:

```
int blockAndRoomIndex = rooms[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()) - 1 + (i * 3));
```

If i==0, this will allow the user to select rooms 0~2 (0*3 + roomNum-1).
If i==1, this will allow the user to select rooms 3~5 (1*3 + roomNum-1).
...
If i==4, this will allow the user to select rooms 12~14 (4*3 + roomNum-1).

If the number of rooms changes, you'd just replace the 3 with another number. Also, I'd recommend defining some constants in your code instead of using fixed numbers (5, 3, 15, etc). That way you can easily change your code in the future. For example:

```
public const int NUM_BLOCKS = 5;
public const int NUM_ROOMS_PER_BLOCK = 3;
...
int blockAndRoomIndex = rooms[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()) - 1 + (i * NUM_ROOMS_PER_BLOCK));
```

Also take Flydog57's comment to your question into consideration. An inline call to `ReadLine()`, and not using try-catch when parsing inputs, is bad practice. However, if you're new to C#, try-catch may be a bit too advanced for now, so just move the inline call to `ReadLine()` to somewhere before its current location.